# Android application getting crashed on click of TDateEdit (FMX Control)

Tags: android, delphi, crash, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I'm using **Delphi XE8** for Android mobile application development. I have used `TDateEdit` for date pick. In some Android device (like Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime , Xiaomi mi) , when i click on `TDateEdit` , the application getting closed without any exceptions.

I'm having only TDateEdit on my form , I have not added any code , only system generated code is there.

Source code is given below ,

```
unit Unit2;
interface

uses
 System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
 FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
 FMX.DateTimeCtrls;

type
 TForm2 = class(TForm)
   DateEdit1: TDateEdit;
 private
   { Private declarations }
 public
   { Public declarations }
 end;

var
 Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

Form design is given below ,

[image]

> Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime device configuration is given below,
>    *OS  - Android
>
>    6.0.1   CPU - Octa-core 1.6 GHz Cortex-A53*

If anyone faced this kind of issue , please help me on this.

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions seeking *debugging help* ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: See , I'm using only single TDateEdit component in my form, when I try to choose a date , the application is getting crashed. I have not added any code there.

Comment: Then it should be very simple for you to create a [mcve] and include the relevant portions of your logcat, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated issue related things here .Let me know , if you have any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the project to Rad studio Delphi 10.1 (Berlin) solved the issue.